# Error message when downloading doctrine-extensions-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, bundle

i have an error while installing doctrine-extensions
(composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle)

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - lcobucci/jwt 4.3.0 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP s sodium extension.
    - lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle v2.17.0 requires lcobucci/jwt ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0].
    - lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle is locked to version v2.17.0 and an update of this package was not reque
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - D:\Codeing\Server\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium` to temporarily ignore these requir
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require stof/
undle:^2.1" if you know which you need.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

What does it come from? and how to solve it?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? If you are using < 7.2 you have to install sodium extension. See this: [Sodium extension PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sodium.installation.php)

Comment: @Adrian98do i am using 8.0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**PHP 7.1 or older**

You have to install sodium extension. See this:[Sodium extension PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sodium.installation.php)

**> PHP 7.2 or newer**

Open your php.ini file and you have to enable sodium extension. (uncomment it)

Search in file this:

```
;extension=sodium
```

After that, restart your php service

Comment: Oh My God bro, it works